# MicroSD in smartphone in USB 'mass storage mode' gets disconnected on random write workload on XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb

I have a 32GB MicroSD in my smartphone (Motorola Atrix 4G). The phone is connected to my Windows XP (SP3) laptop and the micro sd is accessed in 'mass storage mode' i.e. it is assigned a drive letter and is accessible from the laptop. The MicroSD is formatted with FAT32. The MicroSD contains a virtual hard disk (vmdk) comprising 12 extents (2GB in size). My code merges a redo file on a local hard disk with the vmdk extents on the microsd. The code loops over all 'grain table' entries in the redo file and if the grain table entry is non-zero it reads the referenced 'grain' or contiguous group of grains (grain in vmware terminology is a 64k block in a redo file) from the redo file, seeks to the corresponding location in the vmdk and writes the grain to that location.

Problem is that in the middle of this 'commit' operation the MicroSD gets disconnected (not always exactly at the same point in time). I get a "no disk" error message. The event log logs a warning with id 51 - "An error was detected on device \Device\Harddisk2\D during a paging operation". After this error the files on the microsd are no longer 'visible' from the Windows system. After reconnecting the device all files are again visible from the laptop.

So far I have tried the following:

1. Tried different cables, one of them as short as 13'' -> no effect
2. Connected the microsd card (Samsung, class 10 32GB) to the host system through a card reader -> problem did not appear
3. Tried a different microsd (Lexar, class 10 32GB) -> same issue
4. Tried the Lexar microsd with a card reader that is directly attached -> problem did not appear
5. Tried different phones (Samsung Galaxy S2, Motorola Razr M) -> same problem
6. Ran the code on several systems running Windows 7, including the same system that shows the behavior for XP -> Problem did not appear (!!!!)
7. I have an identical 2nd XP system -> same problem
8. I throttled down the write ops inserting a Sleep(500) right after a 'grain' is written to disk -> problem did not appear

Unfortunately 8 is not a great workaround as it slows down the commit operation.

Any ideas anybody?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention that the commit of the redo file was originally implemented in QT using QFile for the image and QFile::write. Having said this ... I re-implemented using the native Windows APIs CreateFileA, SetFilePointer and WriteFile and used the CreateFile flags FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. Now caching is out of the picture and I don't see the eventid 51 message any longer ... but the random disconnect still occurs.